# Spring boot application running locally but not on cloud foundry

Tags: spring-boot, cloud-foundry, pcfdev

I created a basic spring boot application (added in all the JAR files manually, as maven download is restricted in the intranet). When running the application locally, the application starts up (and is accessible on loaclhost:8080), but on deploying the jar file on PCF, i get the following error

```
Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean
```

Since the application is running locally, I am assuming that I added all the JAR files.

What is the issue here?

Comment: Can you please provide the full stacktrace?

Comment: Which version of the PCF JDK?

Comment: Any chance you can use Maven to build?  Maybe at home off your corp network and use that for comparison?  Or get access through a proxy?  I think it would be complicated to manually gather the deps and assemble a working JAR/WAR.